# Cannot get all audio on the device files from Mediastore.Audio

Tags: java, android, audio

I am using contenResolver to query all songs from Mediastore.Audio. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.beethozart

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import timber.log.Timber
import java.io.File

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private fun getAudioDirectories() {

            val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.let {
                it.moveToFirst()

                val pathIndex = it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)

                do {
                    val path = it.getString(pathIndex)
                    Timber.i(path)
                } while (it.moveToNext())
            }
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        getAudioDirectories()
    }
}
```

The problem is that it does not find all songs from the device but only some songs in a specific folder. Here is the log:

```
2021-02-10 14:15:53.793 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Ding.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.793 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Boing.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.794 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Drop.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.794 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Tada.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.794 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Plink.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.794 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Wow.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.795 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Here you go.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.795 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Hi.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.795 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Yoink.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.796 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Knock brush.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.796 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Whoa.mp3
2021-02-10 14:15:53.796 29484-29484/com.example.beethozart I/MainActivity: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack - Incoming call.mp3
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please tell the full paths of files that are not found.

Comment: `getAudioDirectories()` What is in a name?

Comment: @blackapps All the songs not belong to /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.Slack/Notifications/Slack can't be found (for example,/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/audio.mp3) . When I copy another audio file into this folder, then it can be found. For example,

Comment: How are you copying exactly? Or which app does it? And who or how or which app did put those files in that directory which are not found? Or are found.

Comment: If you put just files in directories then there is a great change the media store does not know about them. So how did you? The MediaStore only knows about files if it indexed/scanned them before. What about the Gallery or Foto or Photos app on your device... do they show them?

Comment: @blackapps I copied the audio file using file explorer on the phone. Other apps (music player on the phone) show the copied audio file normally.

Comment: Please reboot your phone for a test. The MediaStore scanner will scan all files again.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work.

Comment: You are using the .DATA column and your Android device does not have version 10 or 11.

Comment: I I tried to use other columns and remove the DATA column but it's no use.

Comment: 10............11  ???